# Javascript: Open popup window in Chrome with hotkey

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to write a window popup function, so whenever person types character v in Chrome, it will open popup. The following is not working, I type "v" on keyboard, and no popup window opens. How can I fix this? Using this in F12 Console to write the function.

```
function doc_keyUp(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 86) {
       alert("Test!");
    }
}
```

Resource Hotkey: https://keycode.info/

Comment: _...whenever person types character v in Chrome..._ What do you mean by "types v in chrome"?

Comment: _..v on their keyboard..._ While they visit your web site? Also where is the rest of the code?

Comment: keyCode is not defined, I assume you meant e.keyCode.

Comment: The keyCode for "v" for me is 86, not 118, not sure if keyboard layouts change this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
    if ( e.keyCode == 86 ) {
        //window.open("url")
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [keyCode Search](https://keycode.info/) to get correct keyCode

[demo page](http://jsfiddle.net/4f3z5dsu/)

```
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
    if ( e.keyCode == 86 ) {
        window.open('http://www.google.com','GoogleWindow', 'width=800, height=600');
    }
});
```

Comment: Why suggest jQuery when it wasn't tagged Alex?

Comment: this is jquery solution, you need to install jquery first

Comment: hi, I am only looking for Javascript native f12 console, sorry

Comment: @mattsmith5 ok i edit to javascript version